When Near A White-hole Would Time (To An External Viewer) Appear to Speed Up?
Disclaimer: I know that a white-hole is purely theoretical, and if it did exist would likely only be able to for a fraction of a second.
But, as being near a black-hole stretches space-time by pulling on it with mass, to an external observer time appears to slow down. So, as a white-hole is semi-opposite to a black-hole, in that it bends spacetime in the opposite way creating “the opposite of gravity”

such as in this graphic 

Would then, an external observer looking at someone relatively close to a white-hole see time speed up (a.k.a see the person move “faster” through the stretching of space-time opposite to a black-hole)?

The external metric is the same for black and white holes, so they would appear to us exactly the same with identical properties and no way to tell them apart.

To observe time moving faster compared to open space, you’d need exotic matter, like negative mass, which cannot exist, because it violates energy conservation among other things.

At least above the quantum scale, negative energy is inconsistent with observed physics. There has been some work done showing that the Casimir effect’s negative energy density does have the effect of advancing the paths of photons across the gap between plates, but it’s a very small difference and the total exotic energy actually obtainable is actually extremely small.


a white-hole is semi-opposite to a black-hole

More specifically, a white-hole is the time reverse of a black-hole. The time reverse of a slow clock is a slow clock that runs backwards, not a fast clock. So time would not go faster near a white hole from the perspective of a distant observer, it would go slow exactly the same as with a black hole.
